# Не могу перейти на другой state

Tags: angularjs, ui-router

Использую `ui-router` для создания структуры роутов в приложении. Заметил, что, когда добавляю в стэйт resolve, то больше не могу перейти по данному адресу. В консоли не выводится никаких ошибок. Структура роутов выглядит примерно так:

```
setRoutes.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];
    function setRoutes($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider

            ....other states

            .state('content.dashboard.my.detail', {
                url: '/:objectId/detail',
                templateUrl: 'path/to/detail/template.html',
                controller: 'detailController as vm',
                resolve: {
                    object: objectResolver
                }
            })

objectResolver.inject = ['$stateParams', 'someObjectService', 'progress']
function objectResolver($stateParams, someObjectService, progress) {
    var promise = someObjectService.fetch(objId)
    progress.showSpiner(promise);
    return promise;
}
```

Есть кастомный сервис который используется в функции objectResolver выше.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('some.module')
        .factory('progressService', progressService);

    var DEFAULT_MESSAGE = 'Loading...';

    progressService.$inject = ['service3'];
    function progressService(service3) {
        var displayedSpinnersCount = 0;

        return {
            showSpiner: showSpiner
        };

        .......... other code
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оказалась ошибка в названии сервисов которые инжектились в функцию для получения объекта. В функции objectResolver я указал зависимость ***progress***, а на самом деле сервис называется ***progressService***.

Проблема в том, что если в функции которая используется в resolve, вы случайно укажите не существующую зависимость(опечатаетесь одной буквой), то переход по данному стейту происходить не будет. В консоль выводится так же ничего не будет. В чем проблема и где ее искать сразу не понятно..

П.С. Надеюсь, что спасу чье-то время.

Comment: ну вообще говоря, при попытке внедрить зависимость которой нет будет ошибка, возможно проблема была в чем-то еще, либо ошибка выводилась выше и оставалась незамеченной

Comment: Вы уверены? Пожалуйста посмотрите этот [планк](http://plnkr.co/edit/FTS8U9lKjMTGuh89J18r?p=preview)

Comment: Да уверен, планк плохой хотя бы потому, что у двух стейтов один урл

Comment: Поправил стейты. Проблема никуда не делась. Может быть вы можете привести этот планк к такому виду, при котором появится ошибка внедрения?